# Neos CMS: Avoid duplication content nodes in multilingual setup

Tags: multilingual, neoscms

I have a multilingual setup of Neos CMS 4.3.. When I create a new page I want to have it in all languages to keep the structure for all languages in sync.

But within the pages I want to be able to create a content node for just  the current language. Is this possible?

When I create a content node and it exists afterwards in all languages I can even not delete it because it is going to be recreated.

I already searched the internet for other people who have this use case
 and try to delete the content node in the language where I don't want to have it.

The content repository language dimension:

```
    ContentRepository:
      contentDimensions:
        'language':
          label: 'Language'
          icon: icon-language
          default: de
          defaultPreset: de
          presets:
            all: null
            'en_US':
              label: 'English'
              values:
                - en_US
              uriSegment: en
            'de':
              label: 'Deutsch'
              values:
                - de
              uriSegment: de
```

I want to be able to be able to manage content within one page in different languages independently.

Comment: I don't get it. It should already work. Every Content Dimension is completely independent.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. For each node that I create in English a node of the same type is created in German. Actually it is not another node but only one which contains two languages. But this leads to that I need sometimes to hide a node in one language because I only want to have it in the other one.